# Reach While variable from outside while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, apache-poi

I must reach variable inside the while loop. I know if i declare variable outside of loop i can reach it. But variable must inside the loop in this scenario. Let me explain with an example;

```
while (rs.next()) {
 HSSFRow row2 = sheet.createRow((short) index);    
 Cell cell5 = row2.createCell((short) 0);
 cell5.setCellValue(rs.getString(1));
 cell5.setCellStyle(stylezones);
 Cell cell6 = row2.createCell((short) 1);
 cell6.setCellValue(rs.getInt(2));
 cell6.setCellStyle(styledatathousand);
 Cell cell7 = row2.createCell((short) 2);
 cell7.setCellValue(rs.getInt(3));
 cell7.setCellStyle(styledatathousand);
 Cell cell8 = row2.createCell((short) 3);
 cell8.setCellValue(rs.getDouble(4));
 cell8.setCellStyle(styledatadouble);
 index++;
 rscount++;
 }
```

This scenario create excel row for every resultset row as you can see. Loop increase row index every time and create new row for new resultset row. Only 3 columns using but list is long as vertical. If i want add data to 4th cell of same row i cant. Because rows already created by loop. If i can reach "row2" variable from outside i can add cell to 4th column just like this;

```
Cell cell9 = row2.createCell((short) 4);
cell9.setCellValue("example string");
cell9.setCellStyle(styledatadouble);
```

Any way create row start from cell index 4 in poi? Or anyway reach while loop variable from outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sheet.getRow(2)` to retreive your row again after the while loop.

Comment: row2 exactly mean excel 2nd row in my scenario. Loop start from add data to 300th excel row. What must i do if i want add data to 4th column of 200th row? sheet.getRow(200) ? Edit: It worked. Thank you very much :)